# Docker - Node keeps saying "Created" or "EXITED (1)"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run `npm run watch-poll` so that my code is being watched while running the docker, however when I'm doing `docker compose up` it's just highlighting in red and saying `CREATED` or `EXITED(1)`

Please find my docker files below:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: customphp/latest
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Node Service
  node:
    image: node:14.17.1
    tty: true
    container_name: node
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - /var/www/src/node_modules
    working_dir: /var/www/src
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_DATABASE: heatable
      MYSQL_USER: heatable
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    bash \
    curl \
    php-cli \
    php-xml \
    php-soap

# # Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install xml mysqli pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl soap gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer self-update 1.6.5

# Add user for laravel application
RUN addgroup -g 1000 www && adduser -G www -g www -s /bin/sh -D www

RUN chown www:www /var/www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

RUN cd /var/www/src && composer install && composer dump-autoload

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
```

Comment: Please show the logs from the running container - what happens before it exits?

Comment: Do you have a Dockerfile or anything else that you need to run the Node image, or are you just using Docker as a roundabout way to run a Javascript interpreter on your local code?  Can you run `node`, on the host, without Docker, to get a live-development environment?